# What is the better way to save state of checkboxes/textboxes? Saving these in ".settings" file is better?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to save state of lot of `CheckBoxes` (checked/unchecked) and some `TextBoxes` on a WPF screen in `.settings` file (As I do not want to use database/filing).

Whether I have to save all these checkboxes and textboxes in setings file or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Use an XML file, then you can quickly serialize the states from file to object and visa-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is to remember the state of controls in an application, I would definitely use user settings to store this. Creating a separate setting for each control can be time consuming initially, but it makes life a little easier later. However, if you don't want to do this, you can simply create a custom settings class with a public  property for each control and then simply use an instance of that class as your one savable setting.

Comment: OK, can then the object of that savable class be saved in one go or we have to write one line of code for each setting?

Comment: No, it can be saved in one go. The only thing to note is that this class *must* be `Serializable`, but this won't be a problem if you will just use primitive types as properties.